# Bring real objects from video feed above virtual game objects in unity vuforia Augmented Reality

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new to Unity and Vuforia. 
I have created a marker image and added 3D vehicles on it, but when I slide my hand towards the 3D vehicles it goes behind those 3D vehicles. How can i make changes to project so that my hand or other real objects from video feed come in front of 3D virtual vehicles.. I have added a screenshot which shows my hand behind vehicles and fence...

[image: My hand is above marker image and below 3D vehicles]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuforia shows the gameObjects infront of camera feed so it is not possible to make gameObjects move behind the real objects that are in camera feed.

I have tried ObjectTargets as well but they are restricted to static objects.
Objects like hands that change their shape continuously by moving fingers cannot become a object target...

So what u are trying to achieve is not possible in vuforia

Answer (score 0):

You sadly can't. AR is pretty new so there are plenty of limitations.

> The Vuforia engine is unable to detect distance as of now, hence
>   nothing that comes in the way of the Camera and the ImageTarget will
>   be displayed since they presume the ideal condition that there is no
>   such disturbances.

But yes, there are ways where you can try to detect a finger by its structure and color and make it an ObjectTarget. Then you could Augmented on top of it a virtual hand that will be shown on top along with your augmentations.

Though, it will not go on top of the augmentations, but rather inside the object.

Hope you get something out of this. Good luck. :)

Comment: you could take this same idea, and make the object that loads on the hand shapes invisible have a culling mask so the objects behind are not rendered, making it appear as though its working.
it could be cool but it'l be fiddly